# Does changed logic IdentityServer4 Scope to ApiResource and IdeneityResource

Tags: identityserver4

I am new at identityserver4 but used identityserver3 before. There are some new configurations named `IdentityResource` and `ApiResource`. But sample applications dos not  include `Scope` any more. What is the difference of `Scope`, `IdentityResource` and `ApiResource`

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for changing all that - better object model, according to the terminology. What is a scope - a resource a client wants to access. But also the scopes were 2 types: identity related and API's, and they were kind of overlapping. So here they decide to switch things a bit and separate them (into resources).

According to one of the authors of Identity server (article [here](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/01/new-in-identityserver4-resource-based-configuration/)) :

> Resources are something you want to protect with IdentityServer – either identity data of your users (like user id, name, email..), or APIs.

**Identity Resources**

> Standard scopes used to be defined like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Scope> GetScopes()
{
    return new List<Scope>
    {
        StandardScopes.OpenId,
        StandardScopes.Profile
    };
}
```

> ..and now:

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    return new List<IdentityResource>
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile()
    };
}
```

And defining a custom one:

```
var customerProfile = new IdentityResource(
    name:        "profile.customer",
    displayName: "Customer profile",
    claimTypes:  new[] { "name", "status", "location" });
```

**API Resources**

Before:

```
public static IEnumerable<Scope> GetScopes()
{
    return new List<Scope>
    {
        new Scope
        {
            Name = "api1",
            DisplayName = "My API #1",

            Type = ScopeType.Resource
        }
    };
}
```

and now:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new ApiResource("api1", "My API #1")
    };
}
```

In the article is explained a bit more, but the main idea is - use the Identity Resources when there is an Identity (Claims principal) involved, and the API resource - when an API requests that certain client **must** have a certain API resource to access this API.

It's a bit confusing in the beginning, but after you try it yourself, it makes a lot of sense. Good luck